# Sharing data in small remote organization

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cloud-gis, data-storage, dropbox

My company's GIS "department" currently consists of myself and another analyst, located in offices several states apart. We have been looking for ways to share GIS data between ourselves as seamlessly as possible, instead of constantly compressing shapefiles and emailing them back and forth, as well as having a central GIS data hub so that new hires can have access to everything we do.

My sense from the limited research I've done is that GIS-focused cloud storage seem to be geared towards larger organizations, or at least the costs are. I'm leaning towards trying dropbox, but wanted to see if anyone else has insight on good programs to use. We both use ArcGIS, and I don't think we'd be looking to change platforms.

Comment: one or other of you could run postgis on a raspberry pi and share the connection details - less than $50 with a .25Tb drive attached

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is migrate to Geopackage instead of shapefiles and stored them inside a cloud service. That's the easiest way to work on my opinion, plus Geopackage works with SQLite so the information is multi platform to.

If you don't know much about Geopackage I recommend you this video to start...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWW-iZCK48c

About simultaneous edith of Geopackage:
[Does GeoPackage support simultaneous editing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294262/does-geopackage-support-simultaneous-editing?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you establish you own GIS server based on a simple computer (or a server, depending on your data volume) with a public IP, running PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Comment: Public IPs come with security/stability issues. Customers might be less than amused by "security through obscurity." Far better to use a true VPN.

Comment: Of course is necessary securing your computer, or the use of a VPN instead, depending on your expertise level.