# What could be the reason for conflicted GPKGs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have a large, complex QGIS project with a total of 20 tables in 4 GeoPackages which are partly linked to each other (via project relations).

For example, I use a relation to link personal data (addresses, etc.) with geometries (buildings). Everything works well so far! But recently, there have been conflicts with the GeoPackages.

This results in "filename [conflicted 1].gpkg-wal" files, entries being lost, or the GeoPackage not opening at all. It is certain that the GeoPackages are only open in one QGIS instance. Emptying the tables completely does not solve the problem. Can a GeoPackage be "broken"? How can I search for and destroy the cause of the problem?

For testing, I changed to GeoJSON - no problems with it in the same project. But I still prefer GPKG.

Comment: Geopackages (SQLITE databases) can be problematic on shared network servers. Have a look at these posts - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397182/using-qgis-spatialite-geopackage-databases-on-shared-network-drives and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402893/why-does-simply-opening-a-geopackage-gpkg-modify-the-file.